# align content underneath a boostrap row where the above columns have an offset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a row of anchors / divs that require an offset-md-1, my issue is the content below the row of anchors needs to align with the row above that has the offset and be responsive. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. When I use margins on the paragraphs the content overflows when viewport shrinks. I also cannot set a max width with margins auto as the row above is not exactly "center" by design. Any ideas? thank you :)

html:

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <a class="offset-md-1 col-md-3 jump-link" href="#">
            <div><p class="font__jump-link">Jump Link 1 offset1</p></div>
          </a>
          <a class="col-md-3 jump-link" href="#">
            <div><p class="font__jump-link">Jump Link 2</p></div>
          </a>
          <a class="col-md-3 jump-link" href="#">
            <div><p class="font__jump-link">Jump Link 3</p></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <p class="p-below-links">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab assumenda at 
            commodi dicta, doloremque
            earum eius libero neque repudiandae soluta.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

css:

```
.p-below-links{
 max-width:1050px
 width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just apply the same offset? Generally speaking, all content in a Bootstrap site should be contained by the grid for consistent behavior.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a class="col-3 offset-xs-1 jump-link" href="#">
      <div>
        <p class="font__jump-link">Jump Link 1 offset1</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="col-3 jump-link" href="#">
      <div>
        <p class="font__jump-link">Jump Link 2</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="col-3 jump-link" href="#">
      <div>
        <p class="font__jump-link">Jump Link 3</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-9 offset-xs-1">
      <p class="p-below-links">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab assumenda at commodi dicta, doloremque earum eius libero neque repudiandae soluta.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/75Leq96b/)